# How to define a global variable in Python from an external class?

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to define a global variable of a class A in Pyhton.
This variable is originated by another class B, in another module, which is instantiated by the class A.
The problems are:

1. Python does not let me import class B into class A "cannot import name Class A"
2. Python let me import in class B the whole module where class A sits but when I try
   to set the global variable from class B I get "global name 'class A' is not defined" error.

in code this is my class A:

```
from moduleB import ClassB

class ClassA:
        global_var = None

        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.classB = None
            self.inst_classB()

        def inst_classB(self):
            self.classB = ClassB(x,y)
```

and this is my class B:

```
class ClassB:

        def __init__(self,x,y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

        def define_var_for_class_A(self):
            # I assign the value here and it is here where the procedure fails
             ClassA.global_var = 20
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The lines `ClassA:` and `ClassB` are invalid syntax. So is `def__init__(...)` (missing space after `def`). Also, `value` is undefined in the `define_var_for_class_A` function. Please provide actual code, not just pseudocode.

Comment: You shouldn't expect circular imports  to work. You can't have A import B, and B import A. They can work, but they are bad design. What is it you're really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to define a global variable of a single class, from another class, which is instantiated by the class that has the global variable. I can't paste the whole code in here as it is way longer than this. This is simplified code. I would like to define a global variable without importing the other class

Comment: Global variables are **global**. They do not belong to a class, which by definition has its own scope. I don't think there is a problem here to solve. I think you've misunderstood scoping and now your class design is messed up, so you think you need a global to fix it. You almost certainly don't, but there's not enough intelligible information here to help you fix it.

Comment: We don't need "the whole code", but we do need _working_ code that illustrates the problem. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry guys I messed up while writing the question but the code above now is enough to understand what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your specific question "How to define a global variable in Python from an external class?", you simply import the external class and set the variable on the class.

For example, consider moduleA.py, which contains this:

```
class ClassA():
    global_var = None

    def dump(self):
        print "global var is", self.global_var
```

You can then import this class and modify the value:

```
from moduleA import ClassA

a = ClassA()
a.dump() # => "global var is None"

ClassA.global_var = 42
a.dump() # => "global var is 42"
```

If you truly mean a global (well, module) variable, import the module itself. For example, change moduleA to look like this:

```
global_var = None
class ClassA():
    def dump(self):
        print "global var is", global_var
```

You can then change the value like this:

```
import moduleA
a = moduleA.ClassA()
a.dump() # => "global var is None"

moduleA.global_var = 42
a.dump() # => "global var is 42"
```

Comment: This would work but I have two classes A and B. A instantiate B, B does stuff and sets a global integer to class A. Now, as circular imports are not allowed ( and this explains why imports are failing) is there a way to set a variable for a class (A) from another class (B) without need to import it (import A in B) ?

Comment: @user3523583: no. In order to modify something you have to have a reference to it. In order to have a reference, you must either import it, or have something else import it and pass a reference to you. Bottom line, you must have a reference to something in order to modify it.